# Keep Javascript running after reload on chrome console

Tags: javascript, google-developers-console

So, I want to check every 15 sec on some website if some words have been deleted.
I have done this:

```
window.setInterval(myFunction, 15000)

function myFunction() 
{
    
    //Check that "words" are not on web anymore
    if ((document.documentElement.textContent || document.documentElement.innerText).indexOf('words') > -1)
        {
            alert("They still here");
        }
    else
        {
            alert("They are gone");
        }
    location.reload();
}
```

But becaue of the `location.reload();` they script can only run once.

What do I do?

Comment: You can use a userscript manager like Tempermonkey.

Answer (score 2):

call timer in window.load and remove reloading of location.

```
window.onload = function() {window.setInterval(myFunction, 15000)};
function myFunction() 
{
    
    //Check that "words" are not on web anymore
    if ((document.documentElement.textContent || document.documentElement.innerText).indexOf('words') < -1)
        {
            alert("They are gone");
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think tampermonkey is what you are looking for https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo